# ¿Cómo indicar versión de python donde instalar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Quería instalar Wxpython en python 27, pero al ejecutar el comando `-pip install wxpython` me lo ha instalado en la carpeta de `python36_32`.

¿Cómo indicarle que quiero la instalación en `python27`?

Comment: Hola Juan, te recomiendo borrar la parte de la recomendacion de lectura ya que eso es *basado en opioniones* y no es algo que se acepta en las preguntas. Lee [ask] para aprender más. Un saludo

Comment: gracias. He consultado mucho por aquí, pero soy nuevo en la plataforma. Se tendrá en cuenta.

Comment: En Windows usa Python Launcher: en la consola le indicas la version  especifica  a usar : `py -2.7 -m pip install wxpython`

Comment: Ha ido genial. Ya está instalado en la versión interesada. Veo que todavía me queda mucho por aprender sobre python. Pero realmente, es adictivo y cada vez más. 
Gracias.

Comment: Y además, funciona el código, jejejeje, estoy como un niño (de los de mi generación) con zapatos nuevos.

Comment: hahahaha https://xkcd.com/353/, una de las cosas buenas de Python es la magnífica curva de aprendizaje que tiene. Además su filosofía de que el código sea legible por humanos ayuda mucho. Una recomendación Juan, si estas aprendiendo Python ahora te recomendaria que uses Python 3 a no ser que uses algún módulo incompatible. Python 2 no se va a actualizar más (no va a haber python 2.8) y el soporte termina en 2020 si no recuerdo mal. Python 2 es un dolor de cabeza sobre todo en cuanto al manejo de la codificación. He creado una respuesta algo más extendida con el tema del Launcher. Saludos

Comment: Te doy toda la razón del mundo, y así lo hace también el mensaje que nos han enviado a los participantes del curso que hago. Van a ir cambiando las versiones de las plataformas que usamos para realizar los ejercicios así como el material didáctico. De todas maneras, ya voy realizando los ejercicios en ambas versiones cuando tengo tiempo y ganas. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando Windows lo más simple es usar [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#getting-started). Si tienes cualquiel version instalada igual o superior a la 3.3 se instala de forma automática por lo que debes tenerlo. Su uso es muy simple y permite seleccionar que intérprete usar en la consola de forma simple.

Para lanzar un intérprete determinado basata con usar py -:

- Ejecutar módulo con Python 3.6:

  ```
  py -3.6 mi_script.py
  ```
- Ejecutar módulo con Python 2.7:

  ```
  py -2.7 mi_script.py
  ```
- Ejecutar módulo con la última versión de Python 2 o 3 respectivamente:

  ```
  py -2 mi_script.py    
  py -3 mi_script.py
  ```
- Ejecutar módulo con la versión por defecto de tu SO:

  ```
  py mi_script.py
  ```

Para instalar una biblioteca usando `pip` se sigue la misma idea:

- Instalar en Python 2.7:

  ```
  py -2.7 -m pip install wxpython
  ```
- Instalar en Python 3.6:

  ```
  py -3.6 -m pip install wxpython
  ```

Comment: Gracias por tan extensa explicación. Comienzo a tener algunos conceptos más claros respecto algunos asuntos sobre las diferentes maneras y formas de instalar.